# Laravel - How do I navigate to a url with a parameter to left of subdirectory

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have to test this Route, but I am not sure how to navigate to it.

```
Route::get('/{type}/Foo/{page}/{date}', 'FooController@index');
```

I understand that URLs usually have subdirectories defined before the parameters in the URL.

I have worked with URLs like this example

```
Route::get('/Foo/{type}', 'FooController@index');
```

> which would have an endpoint that looks like

> `/Foo?type=bar`

Does anybody know how to test a route such as the one above?

Comment: You can just replace the route params with valid values for each param and navigate to the page. For eg: if `type=published`, `page=my-first-blog` and `date=2022-03-05` where **published**, **my-first-blog** and **2022-03-01** correspond to values actually stored in database. Then you can try to navigate to `/published/Foo/my-first-blog/2022-03-01` and see what is displayed.

Comment: You can read further at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i think that you need to clear out a bit the difference between route and query parameters.

In your case you are trying to use route parameters which will actually look something like:

`/{type}/Foo/{page}/{date}` => `/myType/Foo/15/12-11-2021`

Laravel considers the words inside `{}` as variables that you can retrieve via request so you can do something like:

```
$request->type
```

and laravel will return you the string `myType` as output.

In your second case that you have tried in the past you are referring to query parameters which are also a part of the `$request`. Consider it as the "body" of a GET request but i don't mean in any way to convert your post routes to GET :)

The thing with your second url is that:

`/Foo/{type}` is not similar to `/Foo?type=bar`

instead it should be like: `/Foo/bar`

In general query parameters are when you want to send an optional field most of the times in your GET endpoint (for filtering, pagination etc etc) and the route parameters are for mandatory fields that lead to sub-directories  for example `/Foo/{FooId}/Bar/{BarId}`

The thing to remember is that you must be careful about your routes because variables can conflict with other routes.

For example a route looking like this:

```
Route::get('/foo/{fooId}', [FooController::class, 'getFoo']);
Route::get('/foo/bar', [BarController::class, 'getBar']);
```

will conflict because laravel will consider `bar` as the variable of the `fooId` so your second route can never be accessed.

The solution to this is to order your routes properly like:

```
Route::get('/foo/bar', [BarController::class, 'getBar']);
Route::get('/foo/{fooId}', [FooController::class, 'getFoo']);
```

So when you give as a route parameter anything else than bar your will go to your second route and have it working as expected.