# Laravel: How to deal with 2 different forms of url parameters?

Tags: laravel

I feel that it's a stupid question but I'm actually struggling with url parameters.

I've a route: `/dashboard/13-10-2022`

The 13-10-2022 (the date obviously) is an optional parameter. I've a form that can change that date but when I use it, the url parameter take another form `/dashboard?date=24-10-2022`

How can I deal with that date parameter considering the 2 forms of parameter ?

Thank you for your help and knowledge.

EDIT: I think I'm not clear enough;

I would like that `/dashboard/$var` and `/dashboard?var=$var` work the same way...

In my controller, I've a function:

`function showTableau(Request $date)`
which works with `/dashboard/$var` and not `/dashboard?var=$var`

How can I deal with both in my function's controller ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - How do I navigate to a url with a parameter to left of subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72464916/laravel-how-do-i-navigate-to-a-url-with-a-parameter-to-left-of-subdirectory)

Answer (score -1):

Your url shoud be

```
Route::get("/dashboard/{date}", ["TestController@dashboard"]);
```

and you need to send url

```
route("dashboard", $date);
```

it will going to `/dashboard?date=24-10-2022` like that

Comment: my route is the following `Route::get('/dashboard/{date?}', [TableauController::class, 'showTableau'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('tableau');` but when I type in the url "/dashboard?date=24-10-2022" it doesn't work i think it's waiting for /dashboard/24-10-2022